# How to perform a query as argument in PL/pgSQL function which returns JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'm trying to perform select by using already created function which returns JSON which aggregates into JSON array, but I'm getting problem in line where I'm performing a SELECT-clause.
Tables I have problem querying:

```
create table orders (
    order_id bigserial not null, -- this is Primary Key     
    total double precision,
    order_date timestamp,
    user_id bigint -- references `users` table 
);

create table order_item
(
    order_item_id bigserial not null, --primary key
    amount integer,
    book_id bigint, -- FK which references `book` table 
    order_id bigint -- FK which references `orders` table
);
```

My query looks like this in PL/pgSQL:

```
create or replace function public.get_order_by_order_id(o_id bigint) returns json as
$BODY$
DECLARE
    order_items json;
    found_order "vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders;
    found_user json;
begin
    -- other queries left out for code brevity
    
    select json_agg(x) INTO order_items 
    from (select public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(
        select oi.order_item_id -- this is where PROBLEM occurs !!!
        from public.order_item AS oi
        where oi.order_id = o_id)
    ) x;

    return (select json_build_object(
        'order_id', found_order.order_id,
        'total_price', found_order.total,
        'order_date', found_order.order_date,
        'user', found_user,
        'order_items', order_items
    ));
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';
```

...and here is function `get_orderitem_by_oi_id(order_item_id::bigint)` (which works properly and returns JSON):
In line where "**-- this is where PROBLEM occurs !!!**" comment is placed I get an error/warning in **DataGrip**  which states:

> ')',  or ORDER expected, got 'select'

This is how my JSON should look like:

```
{
  "order_id": 21,
  "total_price": 89.92,
  "order_date": "2020-05-03 00:00:00",
  "order_items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 32,
      "amount": 3,
      "book": {
        "book_id": 2,
        "title": "Murder on the Orient Express",
        "price": 19.98,
        "amount": 151,
        "deleted": false,
        "authors": [
          {
            "author_id": 1,
            "first_name": "Agatha",
            "last_name": "Christie"
          }
        ],
        "categories": [
          {
            "category_id": 9,
            "name": "Crime",
            "deleted": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "order_id": 21,
      "total_order_item_price": 59.94
    },
    {
      "order_item_id": 31,
      "amount": 2,
      "book": {
        "book_id": 5,
        "title": "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
        "price": 14.99,
        "amount": 85,
        "deleted": false,
        "authors": [
          {
            "author_id": 4,
            "first_name": "JK",
            "last_name": "Rowling"
          }
        ],
        "categories": [
          {
            "category_id": 3,
            "name": "Tragedy",
            "deleted": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "order_id": 21,
      "total_order_item_price": 29.98
    }
  ],
  "user": {
    "user_id": 1,
    "username": "test"
  }
}
```

My question is is it possible to query for **adequate** order_item_id (**from** `order_item` table) using `get_orderitem_by_oi_id(order_item_id::bigint)` function  by passing adequate order_id in query and if not this way is there ANY other suitable way to achieve this?
Any kind of help in solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** Version of PostgreSQL is **11.8**

**UPDATE1**:

I've edited my Pl/pgSQL function and now looks like this:

```
create or replace function public.get_order_by_order_id(o_id bigint) returns json as $BODY$
DECLARE
    order_items json;
    found_order "vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders;
    found_user json;
    _item_id bigint; -- left it here from @Adrian Klaver's 1st version answer
    _oitems_ids bigint[];
    item_recs RECORD;
begin
    -- other necessary queries left out for code brevity

    FOR item_recs IN SELECT oi.order_item_id into _item_id -- gives an error
        FROM public.order_item AS oi WHERE oi.order_id = o_id
    
    LOOP
        --- Will need to modify to get your final JSON structure.
        SELECT json_agg(x) INTO order_items
        FROM (SELECT public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(item_recs.order_item_id)) x;
    END LOOP;

    return (select json_build_object(
        'order_id', found_order.order_id,
        'total_price', trunc(found_order.total::double precision::text::numeric, 2),
        'order_date', found_order.order_date,
        'user', found_user,
        'order_items', item_recs -- updated value from 'order_items'
    ));
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Error I get when I execute function is:

> ERROR:  cannot open SELECT query as cursor 
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_order_by_order_id(bigint) line 21 at FOR over SELECT rows SQL 
> state: 42P11

Unfortunately I don't have experience with cursors in PostgreSQL and PL/pgSQL (started learning PL/pgSQL less than week ago). Any idea what this error points to and how should this be fixed?
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE2:**
I've edited my query (FOR-LOOP part to be more precise), executed it and got this as result:

```
{
  "order_id": 1069,
  "total_price": 136.94,
  "order_date": "2020-06-10T19:57:40.562",
  "user": 3,
  "order_items": {
    "order_item_id": 2042
  }
}
```

BTW, order_id has two order_items with order_item_id 2041 and 2042 which means that only 2nd order_item is being "caught". Also, not full JSON object is built from `public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(oi_id **bigint**)` function. Any advice how to fix this?

**UPDATE3**:
By made comments I have to stress that `public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(_item_id)` function RETURNS JSON type and here is my updated function which looks like this now:

```
create or replace function public.get_order_by_order_id6(o_id bigint) returns json as $BODY$
DECLARE
    order_items json;
    found_order "vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders;
    found_user json;
    _item_id bigint;
    _oitems_ids bigint[];
    item_recs RECORD;
begin
    select * into found_order
    from "vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders
    where order_id = o_id;
    -- other queries left out for code brevity

    FOR _item_id IN SELECT DISTINCT oi.order_item_id
        FROM public.order_item AS oi WHERE oi.order_id = o_id
    LOOP
        --- Will need to modify to get your final JSON structure.
        SELECT json_agg(x) INTO order_items
        FROM (SELECT public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(_item_id)) x;
    END LOOP;

    return (select json_build_object(
        'order_id', found_order.order_id,
        'total_price', trunc(found_order.total::double precision::text::numeric, 2),
        'order_date', found_order.order_date,
        'user', found_user,
        'order_items', order_items
    ));
end
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';
```

...and **this is result** I get (in JSON of course):

```
{
  "order_id": 1069,
  "total_price": 136.93,
  "order_date": "2020-06-10T19:57:40.562",
  "user": {
    "user_id": 3,
    "username": "mica"
  },
  "order_items": [
    {
      "get_orderitem_by_oi_id": { -- for some reason it INSERTS function name HERE!!!
        "order_item_id": 2042,
        "amount": 2,
        "book": {
          "book_id": 8,
          "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
          "price": 23.5,
          "amount": 298,
          "is_deleted": false,
          "authors": [
            {
              "author_id": 3,
              "first_name": "JRR",
              "last_name": "Tolkien"
            }
          ],
          "categories": [
            {
              "category_id": 9,
              "name": "Crime",
              "is_deleted": false
            }
          ]
        },
        "order_id": 1069,
        "total_order_item_price": 59.96
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reason it keeps fetching ONLY **LAST** record of selected `order_itemS` and keeps inserting function name it result (stated under "*-- for some reason it INSERTS function name HERE!!!*" comment in JSON code). Any idea how to aggregate/collect ALL records into `order_items` **json** variable?

**P.S.** I've experimented in separate function with FOR-LOOP where variables are same (except `order_items`  which is of type **json[]**):

```
FOR _item_id IN SELECT DISTINCT oi.order_item_id FROM public.order_item AS oi WHERE oi.order_id = o_id
    LOOP
        order_items := order_items || json_build_object('order_item_id', _item_id);
    END LOOP;
```

..and it gave ALL IDs for order_item (2041 and 2042, NOT just 2042 like `get_order_by_order_id6()` function).

**UPDATE4:**
Here is function `get_orderitem_by_oi_id(order_item_id::bigint)` (which works properly and returns JSON):

```
create or replace function get_orderitem_by_oi_id(oi_id bigint) returns json
    language plpgsql
as
$FUNCTION$
declare
    found_oi "vertx-jooq-cr".public.order_item;
    book_json json;
    total_oi_price decimal;
    book_price double precision;
begin
    select * into found_oi
    from public.order_item AS oi2
    where oi2.order_item_id = oi_id;

    select public.get_book_by_book_id(public.order_item.book_id::bigint) into book_json
    from public.order_item
    where public.order_item.order_item_id = oi_id;

    select price into book_price
    from book AS b
    inner join public.order_item AS oi USING (book_id);

    total_oi_price = found_oi.amount * book_price;
    return (select json_build_object(
        'order_item_id', found_oi.order_item_id,
        'amount', found_oi.amount,
        'book', book_json,
        'order_id', found_oi.order_id,
        'total_order_item_price', trunc(total_oi_price::double precision::text::numeric, 2)
    ));
end
$FUNCTION$;
```

Comment: The cursor is being created by plpgsql(Postgres) in the background to LOOP over the results of the query and assign the results to the item_recs RECORD. The issue is that I left the ```into _item_id``` in and the cursor code can't handle that.  You might want to create a simple function that uses the FOR/LOOP style just to get a handle on how it works.

Comment: Well that is why I added the comment ```--- Will need to modify to get your final JSON structure.```. I don't know what is happening in ```get_orderitem_by_oi_id()```? I do know that the item_recs  you are adding to ```order_items``` is the record with the order_item_id. If ```get_orderitem_by_oi_id()``` is returning a JSON object/string you will need to add that to some structure in the ```LOOP``` that you have ```DECLARE```d and then in the final ```RETURN``` add that structure to ```'order_items'```.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I've updated my question regarding your comments for my question under **UPDATE3** section, so please take a look.

Comment: Not sure how that function actually manages to execute. The query above the begin and ```"vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders``` should cause it to fail.  I have to believe the "get_orderitem_by_oi_id" in output JSON is there because is returned by get_orderitem_by_oi_id(). You getting only one item because as you ```LOOP``` you replace the value of order_items with the latest iteration of the loop.  You need to ```DECLARE``` something, say an an array, that you can add each iterations order_items to and then add to 'order_items' at the end. I get chance I will see if I can build an example.

Comment: Added alternate method to answer.

Comment: I don't think I understood part 'The query above the begin and `"vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders` should cause it to fail.' ? It works fine. I will try to modify my FOR-LOOP code so that it saves each SINGLE order_item and appends it into array of `json` objects...tried it, but no luck so far. Is there any **appropriate method** which is being used when working with JSON arrays (so I can achieve what I mentioned in last sentence)?

Comment: "vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders implies database.schema.table naming. The community version of Postgres does not support that, so that would fail unless you are using a fork of Postgres that does.

Comment: I see..maybe that's because I'm using DataGrip and it needs to have to that qualified naming.

Comment: But the naming is inside the function and  therefore inside Postgres. Where did you get or are using Postgres?

Comment: I am using Postgres 11.8 on Fedora 30 and Postgres packages are not Fedora's, but from PostgreSQL Global Development Group. You can see more details in my question and answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269473/what-does-psql-usr-pgsql-11-lib-libpq-so-5-no-version-information-available/269479?noredirect=1#comment530668_269479)

Comment: Huh, I just learned something. You can  use the database_name.schema.table_name as long as database_name is the one you are in. You can't do cross data references though. This means "vertx-jooq-cr" is redundant though.

Comment: Interesting...then I could've been that something before was not setup right DataGrip and I had to put "database_name.schema.*" part in order to work. Thanks for clarifying that. BTW, I've updated my answer according to it and if you find it to be OK please vote up +1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a query into a function as an argument. What you can do is something like:

```
DECLARE
    order_items json;
    found_order "vertx-jooq-cr".public.orders;
    found_user json;
    item_recs RECORD;

BEGIN

 FOR item_recs IN select oi.order_item_id
    from public.order_item AS oi where oi.order_id = o_id
 LOOP
   --- Will need to modify to get your final JSON structure.
   select json_agg(x) INTO order_items 
     from (select public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(item_recs.order_item_id)
     ) x;
  END LOOP;
...
```

The above comes from here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Alternate method, without using LOOP:

```
create table orders (
    order_id bigserial not null, -- this is Primary Key     
    total double precision,
    order_date timestamp,
    user_id bigint -- references `users` table 
);
create table order_item
(
    order_item_id bigserial not null, --primary key
    amount integer,
    book_id bigint, -- FK which references `book` table 
    order_id bigint -- FK which references `orders` table
);
insert into orders (total, order_date, user_id) values (100, '06/20/2020', 1);
insert into orders (total, order_date, user_id) values (250, '06/20/2020', 2);
insert into order_item values (1, 45, 1, 1);
insert into order_item values (2, 55, 1, 1);
insert into order_item values (3, 50, 3, 2);
insert into order_item values (4, 100, 3, 2);
insert into order_item values (5, 75, 3, 2);
insert into order_item values (6, 25, 3, 2);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_order_by_order_id(o_id bigint)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    order_items json;
    found_order RECORD;
    item_recs RECORD;

BEGIN
    SELECT
        order_id, order_date, total, user_id
    INTO
        found_order
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE
        order_id = o_id;

    SELECT
        json_agg(row_to_json(x))
    INTO
        order_items
    FROM
        (SELECT
            *
        FROM
            order_item
        WHERE order_id = o_id) AS x;



RETURN (select json_build_object(
        'order_id', found_order.order_id,
        'total_price', trunc(found_order.total::double precision::text::numeric, 2),
        'order_date', found_order.order_date,
        'user', found_order.user_id,
        'order_items', order_items
    ));
END;
$function$
;


select * from  get_order_by_order_id (1);
                                                                                              
 {"order_id" : 1,
  "total_price" : 100.00, 
  "order_date" : "2020-06-20T00:00:00", 
  "user" : 1, 
  "order_items" : [{"order_item_id":1,"amount":45,"book_id":1,"order_id":1}{"order_item_id":2,"amount":55,"book_id":1,"order_id":1}]}
```

UPDATE 06/22/2020 with array. This is a generic example as I do not have time to build your entire setup, but I believe it should show you what needs to be done. In your case capture the output of get_orderitem_by_oi_id() to add to the array. In the below order_item is a test table I set up to hold the two items from 'order_items' above. The rest up the data are dummy values. So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_array_example(o_id bigint)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    order_items json;
    item_recs RECORD;
    item_array json[];

BEGIN
    FOR item_recs IN SELECT order_item FROM hold_json
    LOOP
        item_array =  array_append(item_array, item_recs.order_item);
        

    END LOOP;

    order_items = array_to_json(item_array);
RETURN (select json_build_object(
        'order_id', o_id,
        'total_price', trunc(100::double precision::text::numeric, 2),
        'order_date', '06/22/2020',
        'user', 2,
        'order_items', order_items
    ));
END;
$function$
```

Output:

```
json_array_example                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"order_id" : 1, "total_price" : 100.00, "order_date" : "06/22/2020", "user" : 2, "order_items" : [{+
       "order_item_id": 32,                                                                          +
       "amount": 3,                                                                                  +
       "book": {                                                                                     +
         "book_id": 2,                                                                               +
         "title": "Murder on the Orient Express",                                                    +
         "price": 19.98,                                                                             +
         "amount": 151,                                                                              +
         "deleted": false,                                                                           +
         "authors": [                                                                                +
           {                                                                                         +
             "author_id": 1,                                                                         +
             "first_name": "Agatha",                                                                 +
             "last_name": "Christie"                                                                 +
           }                                                                                         +
         ],                                                                                          +
         "categories": [                                                                             +
           {                                                                                         +
             "category_id": 9,                                                                       +
             "name": "Crime",                                                                        +
             "deleted": false                                                                        +
           }                                                                                         +
         ]                                                                                           +
       },                                                                                            +
       "order_id": 21,                                                                               +
       "total_order_item_price": 59.94                                                               +
     },{                                                                                             +
       "order_item_id": 31,                                                                          +
       "amount": 2,                                                                                  +
       "book": {                                                                                     +
         "book_id": 5,                                                                               +
         "title": "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",                                        +
         "price": 14.99,                                                                             +
         "amount": 85,                                                                               +
         "deleted": false,                                                                           +
         "authors": [                                                                                +
           {                                                                                         +
             "author_id": 4,                                                                         +
             "first_name": "JK",                                                                     +
             "last_name": "Rowling"                                                                  +
           }                                                                                         +
         ],                                                                                          +
         "categories": [                                                                             +
           {                                                                                         +
             "category_id": 3,                                                                       +
             "name": "Tragedy",                                                                      +
             "deleted": false                                                                        +
           }                                                                                         +
         ]                                                                                           +
       },                                                                                            +
       "order_id": 21,                                                                               +
       "total_order_item_price": 29.98                                                               +
     }]}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that doesn't work for my use-case as first SELECT statement only performs insert into SINGLE item_id and I need multiple IDs as `Orders` can contain multiple `OrderItemS` (please review DDL for tables in question).

Comment: is there any other workaround...for instance to load ALL order_item_idS into an array and later perform public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id(order_item_id) function for each element of an (order_item_idS) array?

Comment: See change to answer. Obviously not tested.

Comment: why did you remove `_item_id` in *DECLARE* section? I don't see it being used later anywhere in code... also I get an error when I try to execute created function (please take a look at my update question under **UPDATE1** section).

Comment: Because that was for case where there was a single order_item_id. With the LOOP version you don't need it anymore as you get the order_item_id from the RECORD. As to the error that was my mistake. When I edited I thought I had removed the ```into _item_id``` and I hadn't. See latest edit:(

Comment: I see... Anyway I've tried your solution in updated answer and it didn't work as it should (please check my updated question under **UPDATE2** section). BTW, shouldn't order_item JSON object already be constructed by passing it  `item_recs.order_item_id` in `public.get_orderitem_by_oi_id()` function as parameter?

Comment: I've ran your ALTERNATIVE method, but it gives me ONLY `book_id` while I need more details (like in given JSON examples in my question) about `book` table (besides its ID).

Comment: I'm guessing that comes from get_orderitem_by_oi_id() which you would not share so I had to go with a simpler solution. If you could show an example of what get_orderitem_by_oi_id() does/outputs I could update to a more complete answer.

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer in **UPDATE4** section, so please take a look. BTW, I already gave example what kind of output `get_orderitem_by_oi_id()` function gives in last JSON code as value of for `"get_orderitem_by_oi_id":` key (which is being inserted for some odd reason as key).

Comment: Added generic example with array to hold JSON.

Comment: I've made changes in my code by following examples given in your answer and managed to come up to a solution. Please take a look at answer I've posted and add/suggest if something can be improved. Thanks again for your time and suggestions (as thank you I've marked your answer as accepted) :)

Answer (score 1):

After taking useful advises from @AdrianKlaver I came up to a solution by declaring additional necessary variables to handle each `order_item` in FOR-LOOP and queries to produce a final (needed) result. Here's the final solution which works as it should (made changes by @AdrianKlaver's 2nd answer):

```
create or replace function public.get_order_by_order_id8(o_id bigint) returns json as
$BODY$
DECLARE
    total_oi_price double precision;
    book_price double precision;
    total_price double precision;
    oi_amount integer;
    order_items json;
    item_recs RECORD;
    book_json json;
    single_order_item json;
    found_order public.orders;
    found_user json;
    item_array json[];
BEGIN
    select * into found_order
    from public.orders
    where order_id = o_id;

    select json_build_object('user_id', public.users.user_id, 'username', public.users.username)
    into found_user
    from public.users
    INNER JOIN public.orders as o USING (user_id)
    WHERE o.order_id = o_id;

    total_price = 0.00;

    FOR item_recs IN SELECT *
        FROM public.order_item AS oi WHERE oi.order_id = o_id
    LOOP
        select public.get_book_by_book_id(item_recs.book_id) into book_json;

        select price INTO book_price FROM book AS b WHERE b.book_id = item_recs.book_id;
        oi_amount = item_recs.amount;

        total_oi_price = book_price * oi_amount;

        SELECT json_build_object('order_item_id', item_recs.order_item_id,
        'amount', item_recs.amount,
        'book', book_json,
        'order_id', item_recs.order_id,
        'total_order_item_price', trunc(total_oi_price::double precision::text::numeric, 2)) INTO single_order_item;
        total_price := total_price + total_oi_price;
        item_array = array_append(item_array, single_order_item);
    END LOOP;
    order_items = array_to_json(item_array);

    return (select json_build_object(
        'order_id', found_order.order_id,
        'total_price', trunc(total_price::double precision::text::numeric, 2),
        'order_date', found_order.order_date,
        'user', found_user,
        'order_items', order_items
    ));

end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

...and here is the JSON result I get:

```
{
  "order_id": 1069,
  "total_price": 136.94,
  "order_date": "2020-06-10T19:57:40.562",
  "user": {
    "user_id": 3,
    "username": "mica"
  },
  "order_items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 2041,
      "amount": 3,
      "book": {
        "book_id": 6,
        "title": "The Da Vinci Code",
        "price": 29.98,
        "amount": 297,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "authors": [
          {
            "author_id": 8,
            "first_name": "William",
            "last_name": " Shakespeare"
          }
        ],
        "categories": [
          {
            "category_id": 10,
            "name": "Action",
            "is_deleted": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "order_id": 1069,
      "total_order_item_price": 89.94
    },
    {
      "order_item_id": 2042,
      "amount": 2,
      "book": {
        "book_id": 8,
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "price": 23.5,
        "amount": 298,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "authors": [
          {
            "author_id": 3,
            "first_name": "JRR",
            "last_name": "Tolkien"
          }
        ],
        "categories": [
          {
            "category_id": 9,
            "name": "Crime",
            "is_deleted": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "order_id": 1069,
      "total_order_item_price": 47
    }
  ]
}
```

It turns out that `get_orderitem_by_oi_id()` was **sufficient** and it needed result can be done *without it*.

Comment: See my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I see in your answer. This:

```
        from public.order_item
        where public.order_item.order_item_id IN (item_recs.order_item_id);
```

should be shortened to this:

```
 select public.get_book_by_book_id(item_recs.book_id) into book_json;
```

as you are already on a unique record.

This:

`select amount INTO oi_amount FROM order_item AS oi WHERE oi.amount = item_recs.amount;`

should be:

```
oi_amount = item_recs.amount;
```

because the query might select more then one amount from order_item if there are more then one record with a oi.amount = item_recs.amount. Also you are saying item_recs.amount is the amount you are looking for anyway.

Comment: Yeah, in a hurry to make it work I've overseen those 2 sufficient queries. Thanks for code review. ;)

Comment: Refactored code according to your (2nd) answer. Please give it a look and upvote +1 if you find it to be functional. Thanks again